# Unable to send file attachment named in Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I'm somewhat new to VBA programming so please bear with me. I'm trying to automate the job of emailing my organization's department heads with a standard email but a personalized audit memos. Each email sent to a certain person should also contain the corresponding attachment.

I have a spreadsheet with three columns: name, email address, and the location of the file I'd like to attach in A, B, and C respectively. I've represented this the best I can below.

A....................B..................C

Name.............Email............Attachment

John Smith.....a@b.com.....Q:\PLIU\File1

Jane Smith.....c@d.com.....Q:\PLIU\File2

Jimm Smith.....e@f.com.....Q:\PLIU\File3

This is the code I have so far but I cannot figure out how to attach the file written into the attachment column, as debug gives me "Cannot find this file. Verify the path and filename are correct."

```
Sub AttachSend()
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim intX As Integer
    Dim FileCount As Integer
    Dim MailAttachment As String
    Dim MailAddress As String

    FileCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C2:C200"))

    For intX = 1 To FileCount

        MailAttachment = Application.Cells(intX, 3).Value
        MailAddress = Application.Cells(intX, 2).Value

        Set objMail = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        objMail.Subject = "My subject line"
        objMail.Body = "My message body"
        objMail.To = MailAddress
        objMail.Attachments.Add "MailAttachment"
        objMail.Send
        Set objMail = Nothing

    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Remove the quotes around `"MailAttachment"`. You want to use the `MailAttachment` variable, but currently you're using the string "MailAttachment", which of course does not exist as a file on disk.

```
    MailAttachment = Application.Cells(intX, 3).Value
    MailAddress = Application.Cells(intX, 2).Value

    Set objMail = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    objMail.Subject = "My subject line"
    objMail.Body = "My message body"
    objMail.To = MailAddress
    objMail.Attachments.Add MailAttachment `Remove quotes on this line
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to have worked past that bug. I am now receiving "Cannot add the attachment; no data source was provided." as an error. I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: I can't help you with that, I'm afraid. (And that wasn't the question you asked here; that would be a separate issue. You can start by Googling the **exact error message** you're getting; you may turn up some information there.)

Comment: Thanks I'll do just that!